# SpringMVC jsp view req parameters

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, dao

I am making a spring MVC project. My Admin.jsp page is:

```
<form:form action="/users" method="post" ModelAttribute="user"> 
        <table border="1" >
            <tr>
                <td><a href="/findUserById"> Find a User</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="/edit">Edit a User</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="/update">Update a User</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="/edit"> Delete a User</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="users">List of all the Users</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
```

after clicking on href="users" the request goes to the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String usersList(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        List<User> userList = userService.listPersons();
        // attribute goes to jsp
        model.addAttribute("userList", userList);
        // return users.jsp page
        return "users";
    }
```

my users.jsp page is:

```
<body>
    <table>
        <thead style="background: #fcf">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>User Id</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Role</th>
                <th colspan="3"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="user">
            <tr>
                <td>${user.id}</td>
                <td>${user.name}</td>
                <td>${user.userId}</td>
                <td>${user.email}</td>
                <td>${user.department}</td>
                <td>${user.role}</td>
        <td><a href="<c:url value='/edit/${user.id}' />">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a href="<c:url value='/delete/${user.id}' />">Delete</a></td>
        <td><a href="<c:url value='/edit/${user.id}' />">Update</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</body>
```

On users.jsp page I click a href edit button for each user on the list, the url becomes users/{id}and the control goes to the controller's method that is written as:

```
@RequestMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public String editUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model) {    
        User u=  userService.findById(id);      
        user.setId(id);
        // Delegate to userService for update
        userService.update(user);
        model.addAttribute("id", id);       
        model.addAttribute("userList", userList);
        return "editedUser";
    }
```

I can not figure out how can I get the id of the user from users.jsp to the controller method.
my editedUser.jsp page is:

```
<body>
<h1>Today on </h1> <%= new java.util.Date() %>
<p>You have edited the user with id ${user.id} with info: </p>
${userList}
<p>Return to <a href="login">Login Page</a></p>
</body>
```

DaoImpl is

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDaoImpl.class);
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public UserDaoImpl() {  }
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
    public UserDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
    // ***********************save User*****************
    @Transactional
    public boolean save(User user) {

        // Retrieve session from Hibernate
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        // save
        session.save(user);
        return true;
    }
    // **************update/edit******************
    @Transactional
    public User update(User user) {
        // Retrieve session from Hibernate
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        // Retrieve existing person via id
        User existingUser = (User) session.get(User.class, user.getId());
        // Assign updated values to this person
        existingUser.setName(user.getName());
        existingUser.setEmail(existingUser.getEmail());
        existingUser.setRole(existingUser.getRole());
        existingUser.setDepartment(existingUser.getDepartment());
        // update Use
        session.update(user);
        // return to jsp
        return user;
    }
    // ***********find user by Id*************
    public User findById(int id) {
        // Retrieve session from Hibernate
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        // get user
        User u = (User) session.get(User.class, new Integer(id));
        return u;
    }
    // *************************List of User**************
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional
    public List<User> listPersons() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<User> personsList = session.createQuery("from User").list();
        for (User u : personsList) {
            logger.info("User List::" + u);
        }
        return personsList;
    }
    // *************************Delete a User**************
    public User deleteById(int id) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        User u = (User) session.load(User.class, new Integer(id));
        if (null != u) {
            session.delete(u);
        }
        logger.info("Person deleted successfully, person details=" + u);
        return u;
    }
```

When i run the app all pages r viewed fine upto reaching Users Page but when i click on edit/update href on users.jsp I get this on the console from tomcat7:

```
Unresolved compilation problems: id cannot be resolved to a variable id cannot be resolved to a variable id cannot be resolved to a variable
```

How can i get the id from users.jsp to the controller and where I am wrong? Please suggest. Any similar sample app will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your controller method parameters. Try this:

```
@RequestMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public String editUser(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, Model model) {    
       Integer userId = id; // get your id passed from jsp
       // do whatever with the id 
       // ...
}
```

Assume your `id` attribute is an `Integer`.
Variable id in your methed parameter list matches the {id} in your RequestMapping.

Here is the documentation you can find more information on how to handle path variables:
[Spring mvc doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String usersList(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        List<User> userList = userService.listPersons();
        // attribute goes to jsp
        model.addAttribute("userList", userList);
        // return users.jsp page
        return "users";
    }
```

### 1st thing

@ModelAttribute("user") User user is used when you pass the form from jsp to controller. You used that in list method too. Its wrong. You do not even need it(@ModelAttribute("user")) to show the list to the user.

### 2nd thing

You are taking out [List userList] from the service and returning String. This is also wrong. You can return the List as it is.

### 3rd thing

As injun.Y pointed out, you only need one integer value which came from JSP as ${user.id}. There is no way you should expect the whole JavaScript object that has the same getter and setter with [User] object.

### 4th thing

If you are really not familiar with PathVariable and all that you can use HttpServletRequest.

```
    @RequestMapping("/edit")
    public String editUser(HttpServletRequest req, Model model) {    
      String id = req.getParameter("id");
      User u=  userService.findById(id);      
      //do things here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet:

```
@RequestMapping("/edit/{id}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String editUser(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, Model model) {    
    model.addAttribute("user", userService.findById(id));
    return "editedUser";
}
```

You only need `user` attribute on the edit page. In the above snippet, I have made changes as follows:

- Set `RequestMethod` to `GET`
- Using `@PathVariable` instead of `@ModelAttribute`, as from `<a>` tag you are sending only and `id`.